# JSESSIONID with Java & Jetty & on multple subdomains

Tags: jetty, guice, jsessionid

I use jetty with Google Guice. I init the session in this way:

```
HttpSession sessionRequest = request.getSession(true);
```

I know that the session is always created if it wasn't exist.
I also know that by default this line creates a cookie in the response with the same domain I've requested the servlet (eg. domain.com).

What should I do, If a session created - let's say - on x1.domain.com, then I'd like to redirect the user to x2.domain.com, and I want to keep the JSESSIONID created on the first domain (x1.domain.com)?

I tried to start jetty with init params where I set up the default domain to ".domain.com", but it wasn't the best (although it worked), because, I use this application on different domains (domain1.com,domain2.com, etc.).

So, what is the best way to solve this? I think the best way is to transfer the JSESSIONID somehow to the new domain. But... how? :)

Thank you

Comment: The browser wont send the `jsessionid` cookie to the new domain, per Cookie rules, so what value would there be to having access to the same `jsessionid` on the new domain?

Comment: So the goal is: user1 was logged in and got SESSIONID1 on sub1.domain.com, Then, I store that user1 uses SESSIONID1. So when I want to find which user is the current user, I look for SESSIONID1 in the database. There is a chance that the user will be redirected to a new subdomain, for eg. sub2.domain.com. If cookie was stored on sub1.domain.com I lose the information which user was logged in. So I changed the jetty defaults, and put the cookies on ".domain.com". It worked, but this application accessed on several domains, so I can't just setup jetty in this way. Was it your question?